# Why does I get error while creating a html document object for website URL in VB.net?

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I was trying to generate html document object for set of  website  URL's.
I was sending the form name of the page to generate the object. The first three pages loading fine. When it goes to the fourth page, it is not generating the object,it gives nothing. The form name is common for all pages. But the fourth page contained a class name inside the form definition , which is different from other pages.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

```
    Friend WithEvents AxWbEfile As AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser
    Dim htmObject As HTMLDocument
    Dim i_strFormName as string="myform" /*(form name)*/
    htmObject=AxWbEfile.Document
    Dim objForm As HTMLFormElement
    blnCntrlFoundError = True
    objForm = htmObject.all.item(i_strFormName)
    objForm.action = i_strURL
    objForm.submit()
```

The 'htmObject.all.item(i_strFormName)' is giving 'Nothing'. so I was not able to load the URL. It throws following error ,When it hits the submit function.

```
"500 - Internal server error.There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed"
```

For other pages the value of htmObject.all.item(i_strFormName)' is "{System.__ComObject}".

Comment: You should supply the error message. Without it you probably won't get any answers.

Comment: As I said before,The 'htmObject.all.item(i_strFormName)'  is giving 'Nothing'. so I was not able to load the URL. It throws "500 - Internal server error.There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."
For other pages the value of  'htmObject.all.item(i_strFormName)'  is "{System.__ComObject}"

Comment: Is the HTML valid in the target page? No silly mistakes or missing definitions?

Comment: No I am redirecting to a government  site,which is actually working fine.
        The form details of the target page which throws error is : of the  <form class="littleForm" action="accessController.asp?page=12" method="post" name="myform">